# How can I save items to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a site that can upload three pictures, that page saves some other data in the table in SQL Server, but it saves the name of one the pictures the same for pictures in database.

Of course, the name of the pictures are different in the folder that save.

My code:

```
foreach (var item in FileUpload)
{
    if (item != null)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        string Pic = rnd.Next().ToString() + ".jpg";
        // string Pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        string Path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images/cover/"));
        item.SaveAs(Path + Pic);                     

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            item.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
            byte[] array = ms.GetBuffer();
        }
            lstName.Add(Pic); 
            }          
              }
           else
                {
                    lstName.Add("9.jpg");
                }            
        RContact.InsertContact(t, lstNam);
        ViewBag.Style = "color:green;";
    }
```

and I write in the Repository:

```
public bool InsertContact(tbl_contact t, List<string> PicsName)
{
    db.tbl_contact.Add(t);

    foreach (var item in PicsName)
        {

            t.picname = PicsName[0];
            t.picnamet = PicsName[1];
            t.picnametr = PicsName[2];
            db.tbl_contact.Add(t);
        }

    return Convert.ToBoolean(db.SaveChanges());
}
```

but it save the same name.

Comment: The loop in the repository code doesn't make much sense you have only one copy of `t` but yet you loop over PicsName and set the values of `t` multiple times. Are you actually trying to save multiple rows to your table?

Comment: The wording of your question doesn't make it fully clear what you actually want to happen

Comment: yes,i have three columns in table=>picname,picnamet,picnametr

Comment: I can see that. But you're overwriting them all with the same value each time you loop. Step through your code with the debugger and watch the values, and you'll see the problem. You need to assign each field explicitly, once, with a specific value from the list. Your vertical list structure and horizontal column structure are in conflict.

Comment: Try `t.picname = PicNames[0]` etc

Comment: it saves the same name,too.

Comment: I assume you did `t.picname = PicNames[0]; t.picnamet = PicNames[1]; t.picnametr = PicNames[2];` (and got rid of the loop)? That's what I was meaning

Comment: ohh..,it change,thank you.

Comment: I think you should maybe study how lists work a bit more closely

Comment: yes,i forget that.

Comment: but it saves sometimes the same:(

Comment: and it doesn't work right.

Comment: I can't fix *doesn't work*. Please provide some debugging info. Who knows, if you debug it properly you might even find the mistake yourself

Comment: it works in localhost,but it doen't work in the host true.

Comment: Ok but again I can't fix "doesn't work". That could mean 1000 things. I have no idea what the differences might be in your environment that could cause a different behviour. I also don't know precisely what different behaviour you are seeing. You need to get some more details otherwise I can't possibly help you. Do you understand how to debug your code?

Comment: yes,i debug in localhost and it works true.i changed my code ,look at them again please=>i mean.i upload three different pictures but it save on of them in the database.

Comment: thanks to helping me

Comment: if it works in local then I see no reason why it wouldn't work on the server - unless something is different in the server. Maybe the code is different, maybe something in the database is different. It's really impossible to say. Only you have access to the server. Check everything, and then check it again!